# Method which is using BufferedReader to read a file and returning an array

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I want to create a method in Java which reads data from a txt file and returns an array.
I created the first version of this method - I can say that it works but I have a feeling that the shape of this method is not effective and there is a way to do it much more faster and better...
can I ask you to have a look and let me know what can be done better?

thank you very much in advance for your valuable help

```
    public static String[] reader(File file) throws IOException {
    String array[] = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String data;

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        int i = 0;
        while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("I've just read a line number" + (i + 1));
            i++;

            stringBuilder.append(data + "/");
        }

        if (stringBuilder != null) {
            data = stringBuilder.toString();
            array = data.split("/");
        }

        return array;

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use a StringBuilder and then split. Use an ArrayList and add the lines to it directly.

Comment: Why do you need the null check on `stringBuilder`?

Comment: Unless you really want to write this method, you could also just call `Files.readAllLines(filePath)` (a JDK 8 standard library function).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it is a better fit for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) channel.

Comment: Thank you @Thilo I was looking for a simple solution like this one proposed by you : `Files.readAllLines(filePath)` . This is very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach is possible since Java8:

```
public static String[] reader(File file) throws IOException{
    return (String[]) Files.lines(file.toPath()).toArray();
}
```

If you consent to rather return a `List<String>` the code is even more straightforward

```
public static List<String> reader(File file) throws IOException{
    return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
}
```

Thus questioning the need for a method that just encapsulates this instruction. Maybe you could just remove it and call directly `Files.readAllLines`.